# Upload to Google Docs through email

Tags: email, google-drive, upload

How do I upload a document to Google Docs through an email attachment?

I remember seeing a feature of being able to email my document through and have it saved in Google Docs.

Does this still work or exist?

Comment: If this question means, is there a special email address to which you can send things (like many systems provide, including e.g. Picasa) I have exactly this question.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this *used* to be possible -- I can find references to doing file uploads to google docs from a few years ago, but I see no way to do it now:

[Upload Google Docs via email](http://lifehacker.com/217832/upload-google-docs-via-email)

I checked my Google Docs account, searched the help, and I see no reference to this or anyone else talking about doing it on *today's* Google Docs.

Comment: I think this answers the actual question. Or at least the question _I_ have: Is there a special email address to which you can send files as attachments, like many system provide?  Unfortunately @Jeff Atwood it sounds like you're saying the answer is: No, not anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're logged into both Gmail and Google Docs, then:

1. Click on an email that has an attachment
2. Click the "View" link
3. This brings up the Docs view interface
4. Click the "Save in Google Docs" button at the top right

NOTE: This **does not** work for simple graphic files like JPEG, PNG, etc. They will just open in a new browser window. It **does** work with PDFs, Word files, Excel files, etc.

Comment: It doesn't work with PDFs in Chrome.

Comment: @Alex How do you mean? I'm using the latest Chrome on Win7, and if I click 'View' on a PDF attachment, it opens up in a Google Docs window with a 'Save in Google Docs' button at the top right.

Comment: In Chrome on Mac it doesn't. On mine at list. (Chrome 13)

Comment: @sylsft, 'View' for PDFs in Gmail open in-browser in a page that has [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BUj9D.png) toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a service that allows users to upload attachments to Google Docs via email. It's available at http://sendtogdocs.com

Comment: Where does the text in email-body go?

Comment: The text is ignored. Only the attachments are parsed and uploaded.